# How to include /etc/sysconfig files in RPM generated from install4j

Tags: install4j

I am developing the install4j generated installers for [Openfire](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/tree/master/distribution/src/installer). I am using Install4J 7.0.6.

I can not resolve how to tell install4j to install a file into `/etc/sysconfig`, here's a screenshot of my Files screen.  The installation directory resolves to `/opt/openfire`

[image]

When I build the media, I get this warning:

```
[INFO] Creating media file 'Linux i686 RPM':
[INFO]   Collecting files:
[INFO]     [WARNING] External roots cannot be included in an archive media set. Skipping these entries.
```

and the generated RPM file has no references to /etc/

```
# rpm -qlp openfire-4_3_0-SNAPSHOT-1_i686.rpm | grep etc
#
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of install4j 7.x, this is unfortunately not supported, the RPM can only contain files that are installed into the installation directory.